# Binding different ItemSource inside FlipView DataContext WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-10-mobile, flipview

I'm currently working with a Windows 10 Mobile App. I have a simple DateTime list, like this:

```
public DateTime NextDate { get; set;}
public DateTime PrevDate { get; set;}
// list of date
public List<DateTime> DateList { get; set; }

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    DateTime beginDate = new DateTime(2015, 9, 22);
    DateTime endDate = DateTime.Today;
    DateList = new List<DateTime>();
    for (DateTime date = beginDate; date < endDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
    {
        DateList.Add(date);
    }
}
```

Now I want to show it it the flipview, not only one day but also 3 days: current day, prev day, and next day.

Here is my XAML code:

```
<FlipView x:Name="dateFlipView" BorderBrush="Azure" Height="100"
            ItemsSource="{Binding DateList}" SelectionChanged="dateFlipView_SelectionChanged">
    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- show previous date -->
            <Canvas Height="100" Width="100" Background="#FF7683FF">
                <StackPanel Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Day}" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Month}" Margin="0,0,8,0" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Year}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Day}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </Canvas>
            <!-- show next date -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

The above code just show only one date.

I found a solution that I can add 2 DateTime properties, `NextDate` and `PrevDate`, and in the FlipView, can use Binding `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=ColumnHeadInfo}`. But I don't know exactly what I should do yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by having a custom type list, which will hold your data as below.

```
public class DateTimeModel
{
    public DateTime PreviousDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime NextDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime CurrentDate { get; set; }
}
```

And here goes list population:

```
        DateTime beginDate = new DateTime(2015, 9, 22);
        DateTime endDate = DateTime.Today;
        DateList = new List<DateTimeModel>();
        DateTimeModel model; 

        for (DateTime date = beginDate; date < endDate; date =     date.AddDays(1))
        {
            model = new DateTimeModel();
            model.PreviousDate = date.AddDays(-1);
            model.CurrentDate = date;
            model.NextDate = date.AddDays(1);
            DateList.Add(model);
        }
```

And you can get each model object, added in list to the ItemTemplate context. From DataContext you can access those properties as below.

```
    <ItemsControl x:Name="dateFlipView" BorderBrush="Azure" Height="100"
        ItemsSource="{Binding DateList}" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!-- show previous date -->
                <Canvas Height="100" Width="100" Background="#FF7683FF">
                    <StackPanel Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PreviousDate.Day}" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PreviousDate.Month}" Margin="0,0,8,0" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PreviousDate.Year}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PreviousDate.Day}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding NextDate.Day}" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding NextDate.Month}" Margin="0,0,8,0" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding NextDate.Year}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding NextDate.Day}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Canvas>
                <!-- show next date -->

            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: But when I flip, it will flip both three item! and it's absolutely not what I expected :(